# How to catch java.sql.SQLException?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, try-catch

I am trying to catch java.sql.SQLException in my java spring boot application. I got a good understanding on how to do so on this [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm). But since I am using spring boot my credentials are located in my application.properties file.

**my application.properties to this:**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//SomePathURI
spring.datasource.username= someUser
spring.datasource.password= somepass
```

**Error output**

```
2017-04-04 10:18:13.866 ERROR 11684 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
```

How can I catch this exception and continue running my application. Rather than having the application automatically stop and displays this error? I don't understand how would I do try catches if my connection is in application.properties.

Comment: Something is very wrong, because in you properties you are using a mysql driver and the error is in an Oracle driver.

Comment: @Sigrist fixed. I just wanted to mask my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, your username/password are wrong, you need to fix it. But, you can setup you application to continue without the db connection, just add the following properties into your `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Check more detais here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

But be aware that you need to to validations to check if the database connection is ok when you try to use.

Comment: My username and password is absolutely correct. It works when I log into oracle db. (It's some environment issues). Same code deployed on cf works fine. It doesn't work locally. That's why I want to by pass it, to continue testing

Comment: "spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true"  did not work, still breaks my application

Comment: Yes sir, Nothing has changed

Comment: I misunderstood the `continue-on-error` property. That is just for database initialization, not for the connection. If the database connection is not required for you application to work, you maybe should not use spring-boot facilities, because they required a healthy database connection to properly work.

Comment: My web application, pulls data from the database, unmarshalls xml data from a url. So if my database credentials is wrong. I want the app to continue so users would still be able to see data that is being unmarhsalled from the xml url. Thats why I want to catch this exception so that my app can continue even without database connection.

Comment: My advice still is to not use the spring-boot facilities to create the database connection and do it on your own. Create a @ Configuration bean with @ Lazy initialization in the database connection beans and when you try to use them, you can easily capture and handle the exceptions

Comment: hmm... this would be complicated. Only reason I used spring facilities is so that the database would be easily changed on cloud foundry; without having to change any code.